# How to link the track table _Open data view ListID with a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to append tracking data for a specific send (such as opens) to the original Data Extension used for the send.

For this I plan on creating an update query that will be scheduled in automation studio. The query will target the original data extension and use data from tracking tables.

What I am looking for is where to find documentation/examples on how to link the tracking table ListID with a data extension.

Following is where the ListID is described in the _Open data view.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_open/

I assuming that this information is available for use because it is exposed in the Exact Target UI on the “My Tracking > Tracking Details” page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending to a Data Extension, the ListID won't help you.

All of the activity view data is connected via JobID (aka SendID in tracking extracts).

I'd go from _Job.JobID -> _Sent.JobID -> _Open.JobID in your query.  You an relate the email address in your data extension to the SubscriberKey in both _Sent and _Open.